# Filter from duplicate when executing a function

Tags: javascript

Good afternoon, I have a script that searches for divs by content and changes it, the script is executed when I click on the button, after the click they are rendered or deleted, but if I click on the button, and the content of the div of the last button will match the content of the next button of the div of the past the buttons will not disappear, and because of this, the script will repeatedly try to change the contents of the past divs.
I need that when switching to a new button, the script does not touch the divs that were in the previous button. how to implement it please tell me.
My code:

```js
const boxes = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("btn-default"));
boxes.forEach((box) => {
  box.addEventListener("click", function handleClick(event) {
    console.log("box clicked", event);
    var textProp = "textContent" in document ? "textContent" : "innerText";
    [].slice
      .call(document.querySelectorAll("button"), 0)
      .forEach(function (aEl) {
        if (aEl[textProp].indexOf("All") > -1) {
          function convert() {
            var pageDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("product__price");
            for (i = 0; i < pageDivs.length; i++) {
              const exchange = 57;
              let sum = document
                .getElementsByClassName("product__price")
                [i].innerText.replace("EUR", "USD");
              sum = sum.split(" ")[0];
              sum = sum / exchange;
              document.getElementsByClassName("product__price")[i].innerHTML =
                sum + " EUR";
            }
          }
          convert();
        }
      });
  });
});
```

The code scans the buttons by class, and when I click on them, the page content is updated, and the script changes the contents of the divs, and as I said, if the contents of the buttons match, they will remain on the page and the script will try to change them again, I need the script to not changed past divas, if they remained.

I click on this button

```
<button role="button" class="btn btn-default active" ng-class="{'active': cat.id === Store.categoryId}" ng-click="Store.setCategory(cat.id)">All</button>
```

After clicking, about 5-10 such divs are created with different numbers

```
<div class="product__price">
   111 USD
</div>
<div class="product__price">
   555 USD
</div>
```

After i click on the button again and several divs are created again, but the old div remain, and some old div disappear, I need my script to not change the divs that remained after the click.

When you click on the button, the divs appear in the DOM, on the next click, some of them disappear, some remain, those that remain should not be changed by the script on the next click.

Comment: It's too hard to follow without the HTML and some content -- so include HTML, content, and JavaScript in a [mcve].

Comment: Added, I will be very grateful if you help

Comment: There's an angular inline event handler on the button. It looks like a static method of `class Store` called `.setCategory()` is invoked by `ng-click`. I'm not very knowledgeable about Angular (not going to either since it's no longer supported by Google), so I don't know how that affects the rest of the code.